# Error while loading mod_perl.so

Tags: perl, apache2, mod-perl2

I have installed perl-5.8.9, mod_perl-2.0.7, Embperl-2.3.0 and httpd-2.2.22. And while starting apache, I get the error like the following (broken into multiple lines for readability):

```
httpd: Syntax error on line * of ../conf/httpd.conf:
   Cannot load ../Apache2/mod_perl.so into server:
      libperl.so: cannot open shared object file:
         No such file or directory
```

And by doing `ldd ../Apache2/mod_perl.so`, I got the output like

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00735000)
    libperl.so => not found
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x005e5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00fab000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0041f000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x0084d000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0x00110000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00197000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00163000)
```

Comment: Could be permission issue sometimes. Could you try starting the server with a user of elevated permissions (like if u used admin user to install mod_perl, try starting using that user).

Comment: I have installed mod_perl as super user (root) and I am trying to start the sever as super user.so This issue may not be a permission issue. I have googled this issue many times and I didnt get any proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The question could usefully be moved to the *Unix & Linux* SE.]

You appear to have installed not-quite-compatible packages, *or* one or more packages did not install properly, *or* the installation instructions are missing a step, *or* the dynamic linker defaults are not as expected.

`libperl` is (unsurprisingly) part of `perl`. On some platforms a normal perl default build will create only the `libperl.a` static library, though it is possible to create a dynamic library `libperl.so` instead, or both. Some people favor the `.so` approach, though it can have some performance overheads.

The most likely causes of your problem are:

1. the installed `perl` has only static libperl.a, but `mod_perl` was built against a *dynamic* perl with `libperl.so`
2. the `perl` package installed `libperl.so` somewhere the dynamic linker doesn't look

Addressing cause #1 means finding different, compatible packages (or perhaps a combined package).

If it's #2, you should be able to locate `libperl.so` (somewhere like `/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/mach/CORE/`), or just run `ldd /usr/local/bin/perl` (wherever the new `perl` binary installed to) to see if it knows where it is.

**Before you try any of the changes** suggested below, just run `ldconfig` as root then try again, in case that fixes it.

If you find `libperl.so` under the new perl installation directory, then you can copy that file to your Apache `lib/` sub-directory as Apache should be built (with an ELF `RPATH`) to include that directory in the library search path. If you find it under `/usr/local/lib` then you should modify your default linker configuration (`/etc/ld.so.conf`) to include that directory, and refresh (run `ldconfig` as root).

Your platform is evidently Linux, but you don't state the type and origin of packages, or whether it's a source build, so I can't be more precise...

I'm slightly suspicious that something didn't install properly because the conventional place for Apache modules is within the `modules/` sub-directory, not directly in the *ServerRoot*.